# How to code multiline JavaScript strings?

Tags: javascript

I want to build a long string in JavaScript that is made up of many components and I'd like use multiple lines to make the code easier to understand.  I tried:

```
data = '<!doctype html>
    <!-- HTML5  -->
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Webplaces</title>' 
    + 
    styleBlock 
        +
    '</head> 
    <body>' 
        +
    outerHTML  
        + 
    '</body>
    </html>' ;
```

but JavaScript doesn't like that at all.  Is there a way to do  this?

Thanks

Comment: Escape the newline characters, or build separate strings with `+` concatenation or an Array `.join("")`

Comment: @CrazyTrain: First result in Google for "multiline strings js".

Comment: @elclanrs: Yep, first among many, many results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make each new line its own string and concatenate them:

```
data = "<!doctype html>"+
    "<!-- HTML5  -->"+
    "<html>"+
    "<head>"+
    "<meta charset="utf-8" />"+
    "<title>Webplaces</title>"+
    styleBlock+
    "</head>"+ 
    "<body>"+
    outerHTML+
    "</body>"+
    "</html>";
```

It is possible to escape the lines with a slash `\` like this:

```
text = "This line will \
    end here";
```

But that isn't recommended because the whitespace (indent) that appears at the beginning of each line can possibly lead to errors.